# Analog clock not accounting for current time

Tags: javascript

## Preface - I'm new to programming and appreciate any assistance.

I followed a youtube guide to code an analog clock but my JavaScript functions are not creating a 'live' clock. I have reviewed my code against and video and corrected some discrepancies but I am still unable to get this clock functioning.

Would anyone be able to help suggest where i am going wrong?

Code attached as snapshot.[Javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8QwM.png)[CSS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aiLY.png)

Youtube guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94TKO4eKfIA

Code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Javascript Clock</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="clock">
  <div class ="hour">
   <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="min">
   <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sec">
   <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  const deg = 6;
  const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
  const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
  const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");
  setInterval(() => {
   let day = new Date();
   let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
   let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
   let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;
   hr.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${hh+(mm/12)}deg)';
   mn.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${mm}deg)';
   sc.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${ss}deg)';
  })
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A snapshot of code is like a picture of a book...how useful is that? Cut and paste the content of `style.css` in the CSS box of your [mcve]. Or better yet add `<style>` **ALL THE CSS IN HERE** `</style>` into the `<head>...</head>`

Comment: To see how to create a snippet, check this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/  This will give you all info to create a working snippet on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, good work so far. 
You might want to have a look into the documentation for [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval). You just forgot the second argument (delay). Your code should look like:

```
setInterval(() => {
            let day = new Date();
            let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
            let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
            let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;
            hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${hh+(mm/12)}deg)`;
            mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
            sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
        }, 1000)
```

1000 means the function will be called every 1000 ms and this will update your ui.

Edit: incorporated backticks as suggested in the comment from [Adriano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5390321/adriano)

Comment: The clocks hands are still all pointed at 12pm. Could this be an error due to using google chrome?

Comment: without your CSS file @pulls who can say

Comment: @pulls: no, it is an error, because you wrote the wrong character. It has to be `\`` and not `'`

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval needs a time delay as a second parameter like this for example `setInterval(function(), 1000);`

So your code would look something like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Javascript Clock</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="clock">
  <div class ="hour">
   <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="min">
   <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sec">
   <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  const deg = 6;
  const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
  const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
  const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");
  setInterval(() => {
   let day = new Date();
   let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
   let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
   let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;
   hr.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${hh+(mm/12)}deg)';
   mn.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${mm}deg)';
   sc.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${ss}deg)';
  }, 1000);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a basic clock try to understand how it works rather that repeating the youtupe guide. no offence :P

```
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();  
  //to get the the value of the current time of your country and apply it to "today".

  var h = today.getHours();  //"today" here is the var, it's not a constant.
  var m = today.getMinutes(); 
  var s = today.getSeconds();

  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

  var refresher = setTimeout(startTime, 500); 
  //the setTimeout here is to keep initiating the function as named in the first 
  //parameter and the second parameter is the time it waits before it initiates 
  //again, so basically the function is just to display the time at the moment
  //and the timeout is to keep showing it every second, try changing the number 
}


function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  //this add zero in front of numbers < 10, youll get it 
                              //when learning the if statement.
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Fair comment Hannon. I'll try go from scratch with another beginner project and see how I go.

Comment: I suggest you study at w3schools, Also please upVote and check the answer that fits the question the most for other people.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Javascript Clock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clock">
        <div class ="hour">
            <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="min">
            <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sec">
            <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const deg = 6;
        const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
        const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
        const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");
        setInterval(() => {
            let day = new Date();
            let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
            let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
            let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;
            hr.style.transform = 'rotateZ(' + (hh + (mm / 12)) + 'deg)';
      mn.style.transform = 'rotateZ(' + mm + 'deg)';
      sc.style.transform = 'rotateZ(' + ss + 'deg)';
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `   and not ' . Check Below Corrected Code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Javascript Clock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clock">
        <div class ="hour">
            <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="min">
            <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sec">
            <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const deg = 6;
        const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
        const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
        const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");
        setInterval(() => {
            let day = new Date();
            let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
            let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
            let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;
            hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${hh+(mm/12)}deg)`;
            mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
            sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const deg = 6;
      const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
      const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
      const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");
      setInterval(() => {
        let day = new Date();
        let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
        let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
        let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;
        hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${hh + mm / 12}deg)`;
        mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
        sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
      });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].